# Libpointmatcher : Error ICP failed to Converge

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I am using libpointmatcher package for finding transformation between two 2D pointclouds (Using RPlidar sensor) .
But some times it gives me an Error :

"[ERROR] [1514615155.146144153]: ICP failed to converge: "

Please can anyone suggest me in which situation I will be getting this type of an error . Or does it haves any limitation .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/278736/libpointmatcher-:-error-icp-failed-to-converge/) by [Aasiya Shaikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27804/aasiya-shaikh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2018-01-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Registering two partially overlapping point clouds is a very challenging task and the ICP algorithm doesn't always find a good solution, as you have discovered with the error messages you've seen.

These failures are usually caused by an insufficient overlap between the two clouds or the initial starting point for ICP being too far away from the correct solution.

I'd recommend reading up on ICP [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_closest_point) and [here](https://www.mrpt.org/Iterative_Closest_Point_%28ICP%29_and_other_matching_algorithms) if you haven't already. You may be able to improve performance be estimating the point normals and including these in the matching algorithm depending on the implementation of ICP you're using.

---

Originally posted by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) with karma: 9529 on 2018-01-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Aasiya Shaikh](https://answers.ros.org/users/27804/aasiya-shaikh/) on 2018-01-16**:
Thank you sir, it helped a lot.

**Comment by [PeteBlackerThe3rd](https://answers.ros.org/users/25185/peteblackerthe3rd/) on 2018-01-16**:
Thanks Aasiya, if this helped you solve the problem could you accept the answer so this is useful for others.